# Silverlight opacity clip

Tags: wpf, silverlight, opacity

Can the opacity of a clipped region be adjusted? Can you actually say for the stuff that is not in the clipped region, show it at some level of opacity?

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to look into Opacity Masks

http://silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/08/25/terrain-tutorial-part-3-creating-smooth-tile-transitions-using-opacity-masks.aspx

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808222311/http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2008/10/22/working-with-opacity-masks.aspx)

Comment: hmm, i looked at it but that seems to be givin you something to show    in the opaque region?  i want to show the actual thing being hidden, but with a level of opacity.

Comment: maybe, i dont actually want a clipped region. Maybe, I want to have a region showing one image on the background, and a polygon defining  a specific opacity setting overlayed on that image....